# Пагинация в Tarantool

Tags: база-данных, tarantool

В документации Tarantool так и не смог найти информацию о пагинации. Может быть здесь кто-нибудь подскажет, есть ли пагинация в Tarantool (если нет, то как лучше ее там реализовать)?

Comment: а что такое пагинация в БД в вашем представлении?

Comment: В SQL базах данных можно делать через курсосы или через лимиты, например 1..10, 11..20 и так далее - для того, чтобы на сайте работала пагинация